# bash cut command: why is my script not cutting?

Tags: bash, parsing

All:

Good evening!

I'm using `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS` with `bash 4.4.20`.

Here is my script:

```
        results=`echo "SELECT cacheuid,status,expire from imagecache where rawline = '$line';" | mysql -u$mysql_user -p$mysql_pass -D$mysql_db -h$mysql_host -s 2> /dev/null`
        if [ -z "$results" ]
        then                                                    # The cache look up failed.
                echo "\$results is empty"
        else                                                    # The cache look up succeeded.
                echo "\$results is NOT empty.  It is = $results"
                cacheuid=$(echo "$results" | cut -d " " -f 1)
                stat=$(echo "$results" | cut -d " " -f 2)
                expire=$(echo "$results" | cut -d " " -f 3)

        fi

                echo "Query Results   : '$results'"
                echo "CacheUID        : $cacheuid"
                echo "Status          : $stat"
                echo "Expire Time     : $expire"
```

And here are the results:

```
$results is NOT empty.  It is = 1       waiting 1588636095
Query Results   : '1    waiting 1588636095'
CacheUID        : 1     waiting 1588636095
Status          : 1     waiting 1588636095
Expire Time     : 1     waiting 1588636095
```

I am expecting these results:

```
$results is NOT empty.  It is = 1       waiting 1588636095
Query Results   : '1    waiting 1588636095'
CacheUID        : 1
Status          : waiting
Expire Time     : 1588636095
```

Where am I going wrong in my cuts?

Thanks!

Comment: You are splitting on spaces, but the string contains tabs

Comment: If your input is tab-separated (instead of white space separated), omit the "-d" parameter. So, instead of |cut -d " " -f 1| try |cut -f 1| (same for the other cut commands)

Comment: Or use 'awk { print $1 }' instead of "cut -f 1", and 'awk { print $2 }' instead of 'cut -f 2', etc

Comment: All good thoughts, all good thoughts!  Please post it as an answer so I can award you points.

Comment: Even if it were spaces, not tabs, when you use `-d " "` it is literally counting each individual space as a delimeter. So `1       waiting 1588636095` with 7 spaces after the 1, when you do `cut -d " " -f 2` the second field is literally nothing. That's what's after the first space. As has been suggested already, I would try `awk`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or use `awk { print $1 }` instead of `cut -f 1`, and `awk { print $2 }` instead of `cut -f 2`, etc – Philipp Claßen

Answer (score 0):

There are spaces before start of the string and in multiple spaces in between words. Try

```
results=$(echo "${results}" | sed 's/^ *//' |  tr -s " ")
```